# Setting a vector equal to {};

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, variable-assignment, initializer-list

Is the following code always valid or is it compiler/platform-dependent? Obviously I could have initialized `edges` using the value constructor, but I am curious to see if the copy assignment `operator=` works here when `edges` is initialized to size 0, and then set equal to a braced r-value.

It works on my macbook.

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> edges;
edges = {{1,2,3},{4},{5,6}};
```

Comment: What are you worrying about? `std::vector` has an [`operator=`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator%3D) taking `std::initializer_list<T>`.

Comment: @songyuanyao In C++, does a list of things enclosed with curly braces always equate to std::initializer_list<T>?

Comment: Not always. Functions taking `std::initializer_list<T>` would be preferred when passed braced-list.

Comment: Oh I see. I guess my question was inspired by the fact that I wasn't sure the right hand side of `edges =` defaulted to an std::initializer_list<T>.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's valid (since C++11). `std::vector` has an overloaded [`operator=`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator%3D) taking `std::initializer_list`.

> Replaces the contents with those identified by initializer list `ilist`.

And [`std::initializer_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) could be constructed from braced-list in specified contexts.

(emphasis mine)

> A `std::initializer_list` object is automatically constructed when:
>
> - a *braced-init-list* is used to [list-initialize](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) an object, where the corresponding constructor accepts an `std::initializer_list` parameter
> - **a *braced-init-list* is used as the right operand of [assignment](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_assignment#Builtin_direct_assignment) or as a [function call argument](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Implicit_conversion_sequence_in_list-initialization), and the corresponding assignment
>     operator/function accepts an `std::initializer_list` parameter**
> - a *braced-init-list* is bound to [auto](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto), including in a [ranged for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)